# How can I open app from remote notification action button

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

As in subject, I'm trying to open app when user taps 'Accept' button on remote notification.

Below is listed `AppDelegate` method which is responsible for handling button action:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification  completionHandler: (void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString: @"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER"]) {

    }

    completionHandler();
}
```

I was looking for solution awhile but I can't find helpful information for me.

---

---

**Update:**
Because sentence 'Actionable notification buttons' cause confusion, img below shows what I mean by this sentence.

[image]

Comment: what accept button on local notification? cOuld you be more specific ?

Comment: As we know we can define remote notification action buttons, one of my button is named 'Accept'.

Comment: isnt the app open when u tap on notification . I think this is the default behaviour for the push notifications.

Comment: yes when you tap into notification itself apps will open, but if you tap into notification actionable button it doesn't open the app by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you register the device for notifications you do it with a **UIUserNotificationSettings**:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[self createUserNotificationSettings]];
```

For instance, in this method you can create the **UIUserNotificationAction** which are the action buttons and custom settings:

```
- (UIUserNotificationSettings *) createUserNotificationSettings {
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[action1 setActivationMode: UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
[action1 setTitle:@"Title1"];
[action1 setIdentifier:@"first_button"];
[action1 setDestructive:YES];
[action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[action2 setActivationMode: UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
[action2 setTitle:@"Title2"];
[action2 setIdentifier:@"second_button"];
[action2 setDestructive:NO];
[action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[actionCategory setIdentifier:@"ACTIONABLE"];
[actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

return [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];
 }
```

When you receive the notification the following method gets called and you can check which button was pressed:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification  completionHandler: (void (^)())completionHandler {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString: @"first_button"]) {
        NSLog(@"First notification button was pressed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Second notification button was pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not answer for my question. Implementation presented in your answer has been made by me and it works great, but my question was how can I bring application to foreground using 'handleActionWithIdentifier' method according to clicked button?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationAction_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIUserNotificationActivationMode

Comment: Yup, you have right I didn't read your code carefully. Thanks man!

Comment: I edited the code to change the UIUserNotificationActivationMode type since i wrote for background on the answer. I didn't read your question correctly but it is edited now (:

Answer (score 19):

Swift 4:

Just make sure you include `.foreground` to your UNNotificationAction object.

Example:

```
// This will cause the app to launch in the foreground:
let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "showAction", title: "Show", options: [.foreground])

// This will not:
let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "showAction", title: "Show", options: [])
```

Answer (score 5):

swift 5:

```
let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "sample", title: "sample", options: [UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground])
```

the UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground gives you the application launch in the foreground and your code runs even the app is force closed.

after creating your action. assign it to the category.

```
let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "sample", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
```

then assign the category

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have been looking for the .foreground option for over two hours (of course I didn't know  that it was what I was looking for)